# functions and set of numbers

Tags: functions

Denote $f$ : $N\to N$ a function
for any $n$ $\in$ $N$ we will mark $A_n = \{0,1,2,3,4...,n\}$ and $A(-1) = \emptyset$.
I need to prove that $f$ is one to one function if and only if $f[A_n] \neq f[A_m]$ for every $m,n \in N \cup \{-1\}$ and $m\neq n$.

how can I approach this function at first? f.e what is the image of $f[A_5]$?
then the proof that it's one to one...

Thanks.

Comment: Groups are a specific thing in mathematics and not the thing you are looking at here. The word for the thing you have here is a "set".

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I have edited the title.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
A_{-1}\subset A_0\subset A_1\subset A_2\subset\cdots
$$
By definition of the term "function", and the notion of a function applied to a set, this means that we have
$$
f(A_{-1})\subseteq f(A_{0})\subseteq f(A_{1})\subseteq f(A_{2})\subseteq\cdots
$$
Now, let's see what it would mean if we had equality anywhere in this chain. Say $f(A_{k-1}) = f(A_{k})$. That means that $f(k)\in f(A_{k-1})$. This implies that there is some $i\in A_{k-1}$ such that $f(k) = f(i)$. So $f$ cannot be one-to-one.

On the other hand, let's say $f$ is not one-to-one. Let $i<j$ be two natural numbers such that $f(i) = f(j)$. Then $f(j) = f(i)\in f(A_{j-1})$, which means that $f(A_j) = f(A_{j-1})$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am still struggling to understand how function work on sets?
for example is $f[A_5]$ = {$0,1,2,3,4,5$}? i mean this function is like the identity function?               
When you refer to $f(i)$ does it mean a number in a set? for example, $f(0)$ in any group would be number $0$?

Comment: @OO1 $f(A_5) = \{f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4), f(5)\}$. And when I refer to $f(i)$, I mean $f(i)$ as normal. For instance, $f$ could be the function "add $3$", and in that case, $f(A_5) = \{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$ and $f(i) = i+3$. Or $f$ could be the function "constantly $8$", in which case $f(A_5) = \{8\}$ (duplicates are redundant, and therefore removed) and $f(i) = 8$. Or $f$ could be something entirely different.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks Arthur.